# JavaScript function is not defined with Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, function, npm, webpack

First , code in resources/js/app.js

```
function button1Clicked(){
  console.log('Button 1 is clicked');
}
```

Second , code in testing.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="button1Clicked()">Button 1</button>
  <button onclick="button2Clicked()">Button 2</button>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/app.js') !!}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function button2Clicked(){
      console.log('Button 2 is clicked');
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

After `npm run dev` and testing in localhost

[image]

As a result, JavaScript function `button1Clicked()` in `resources/js/app.js` is not defined. but the function `button2Clicked()` in `testing.blade.php` can be defined.
Is it a bug from Laravel Mix or I did some mistakes

Comment: Could you add the complete contents of your `webpack.mix.js` and `app.js` files?

Comment: iCoders is correct, you need to use `{{ }}` and not `{!!` because `{!!` are used to display unescaped content

Comment: @iCoders i have tried change it to {{ but still doesn't work

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp I completed the content already and checked the script is in my public/js/app.js too

Answer (score 63):

I had the same problem as you.

It turned out that when Laravel-mix, aka Webpack, compile the js, it wraps our function in a closure.

For example, when we define a function like this

```
function setlocale(code) {
     console.log(code);
}
```

Webpack will generate into

```
(function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

     function setlocale(code) {
         console.log(code);
     }

});
```

That's why we can access the variables or functions inside that closure, but we cannot from the outside as it limits our scope.

A simple solution is setting our function into `window` variable, which is a global variable.

```
window.setlocale = function (code) {
    console.log(code);
}
```

Comment: omg, it works now. i do like this. 
window.YourFunction = function(ParamIfHaveParam){ // yourcode }

Comment: For better understanding  `window.yourVariable = function (code) { ... }`

Comment: It's quite old topic but I would like to ask you, why does webpack put our function in closure? Does it have some advantages?

Comment: Hi MatějČerný, Webpack does that strategy to prevent the pollution of global environment.

Answer (score 7):

update the code in resources/js/app.js as below-

```
button1Clicked = function(){
    console.log('Button 1 is clicked');
};
```

then it will be available for global scope.

Comment: Had to search a long time to find this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you! :)

Answer (score 2):

You just use this top of your js file.

```
window.prototype = this;
```

Comment: In what js file must one add the above code?

Answer (score 0):

As window object is not accessible when building/packaging assets through laravel mix / webpack, so thats why onclick event handler becomes undefined for the code itself. So if the window.setlocale approach doesn't fit well with you then an alternative would be to bind using the jQuery click event e.g.

```
$("#button-id").on("click",function() => {
       // enter code here
})
```